# Intellij Idea hide *.log files

Tags: intellij-idea, logging

Some code create log files in the java project. But then Intellij Idea hide *.log files in the project structure and its visible in the any explorer. 
This is a common problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!
File -> Settings -> Editor -> Recognized file types -> +(right bar) -> add name (for example - log), description, OK -> Registered patterns -> + (add in field *.log) -> OK -> Agree with warning -> Profit!